# What would be the most simple following target and neighbors avoidance algorithm in 2D space on plane?

Tags: 2d, algorithm, ai, performance, collision-avoidance

I have ~20 or more enemies and they need to follow a target and avoid to go on top of themselves. I mean follow a target and avoid to collide with each other. Area, on which they are walking, is just a rectangle plane in 2D space.
What would be the most simple and efficient algorithm for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Closely related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2497/is-there-a-simple-way-to-stop-enemies-standing-in-the-same-spot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is frequently referred to as [flocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flocking_%28behavior%29) or a [boids](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) simulation. It's an algorithm that combines three behaviors to simulate the motion of a group:

[image] **Separation**: steer to avoid crowding local flockmates
[image] **Alignment**: steer towards the average heading of local flockmates
[image] **Cohesion**: steer to move toward the average position of local flockmates

The combination of those three will create a good approximation of a group moving together. These behaviors are described well in the GDC99 paper [Steering Behaviors For Autonomous Characters](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/) (Craig W. Reynolds). Additionally there's a few Java demos of flocking and some other steering behaviors in action [here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/). The other behaviors include a path following steering behavior and a follow the leader behavior that can be useful to you for having a group move along a path.

Comment: Very good explanation, and the pictures are helpful. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you want steering behaviors, specifically [Flocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flocking_%28behavior%29). This enables you to have entities that will flock towards a certain point / target - if you can combine this with [Avoidance behaviors](http://rocketmandevelopment.com/2010/07/13/steering-behaviors-obstacle-avoidance/) you should be able to achieve what you want.