# Enemies are penetrating in each other when following player

Tags: unity, c#, navmesh

[image]

As you can see the image my enemy (when following my player), penetrate each other. How can i avoid it? I am using NevMeshagent to follow the player.

```
void Update () {
    currentNavMeshAgent.destination = player.transform.position;
}
```

I have added a Rigidbody and a Collider to my enemy object but they are still penetrating each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid penetration, increase each [NavMeshAgent](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshAgent.html)'s radius so it's equal to or larger than your agent's collider.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this, but, based on the image you posted i assume that your "enemies" are zombies, so, they don't have or need to "think" by themselves, right?

In this particular case I'd bet for a swarm approach, by doing this instead of managing each of the zeds one by one, you can have a logic 2D Matrix and check where your monsters are before moving, by A* or any other pathfinding approach you want to use.
By doing this, you would be able to skip AABB collision checks between your enemy entities, boosting your performance and knowing that your main enemy puppet master wont let them collide.

Comment: NevMesh based on A* also. I guess